# Apigility: I don't use hydrators. Is Apigility still a good fit?

Tags: web-services, rest, laminas-api-tools

I am investigating Apigility as a way to add REST services to my ZF2 application however I see that it uses hydrators.  My domain objects are created by factories which validate and filter data, add proxies, etc, then instantiate and return an object of the required type.  The factory injects the domain object data via the constructor.

It seems to me that I need to change the workflow for how Apigility creates domain objects.  In my case it will need to instantiate a factory and feed the inputs to it.  Does this sound right?  Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should not be a problem.

You can inject your resource factories inside [your resource listener instance](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-rest#zfrestabstractresourcelistener). Inside the methods of your listener (`create`, `update`, etc) you can use your factory to do its job (for example create a resource) and then you return a `Hal\Entity` or `Hal\Collection` as a result.

Hydrators are mostly used inside the `Hal` plugin for extracting data while rendering your (nested) resources. In case case you return a `Hal\Entity` or `Hal\Collection` instance directly from your listeners the plugin won't be needing any hydrators. The only condition is that the content of your Hal resources is json serializable (so no complex objects).